# Hello, am trying to run an android project wiritten in Kotlin and am having an issue resolving builder() in DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this)

Tags: kotlin, dagger

These are my imports
build.gradle

`

```
  // Dagger dependencies
    def dagger_version = "2.40"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"`
```

package level imports

```
  import dagger.android.AndroidInjector import dagger.android.DaggerApplication
```

code snippet

```
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> =                                     .     DaggerAppComponent.Builder().create(this)
```

I have tried different dependency injections to see if am missing something at build time but i havent got any positive results

Comment: the code is ```
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> =
        DaggerAppComponent.Builder().create(this)```